# React Native count state not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state, use-state

I want my app to show one textinput, and when you start writing in the first one, the app will show a second textinput and so on... 
The problem with my code below is that the counter always stays at zero. I have tested that the thread goes into the if-statement via console.log(), but the counter does not change and i'm starting to go crazy

```
     import React from 'react';
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Button, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, FlatList } from 'react-native';

    import colour from '../constants/Colors';
    import StartButton from '../components/Buttons/BackToBackButton';

    function ShowNames(props) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.lineContainer}>
                <TextInput
                    style={{ width: '70%', height: 40, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 2 }}
                    placeholder='Legg in navn her'
                    placeholderTextColor='white'
                    selectionColor='black'
                    onChangeText={props.handleTextChange}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }



    export default function BackToBack(props) {

        const [nameList, setList] = useState([]);
        const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
        const [textInputList, setInputList] = useState([{key: '2.9204739', value: <ShowNames handleTextChange={(text) => handleTextChange(text, counter)} />}])


        const handleTextChange = (text, id) => {
            tempList = nameList
            tempList[id] = text
            setList(tempList)

            console.log("ID: " + id)
            console.log("Counter: " + counter)

            if (id == counter) {
                console.log("yo")
                setCounter(counter + 1)
                AddNameInputs()
            }
            console.log(nameList)
        }



        function AddNameInputs() {
            const temp =
                <View style={styles.lineContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={{ width: '70%', height: 40, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 2 }}
                        placeholder='Legg in navn her'
                        placeholderTextColor='white'
                        selectionColor='black'
                        onChangeText={(text) => handleTextChange(text, counter)}
                    />
                </View>
            setInputList([...textInputList, {key: Math.random().toString(), value: temp}])
        }



        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList data={textInputList} renderItem={itemData => itemData.item.value} />
                <StartButton title={"Start!"} height={100} />
            </View>
        )
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: colour.lightTurquoise,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            paddingTop: 20,
            paddingBottom: 20
            // borderWidth: 4,
            // borderColor: 'yellow'
        },
        lineContainer: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            paddingBottom: 20

        }

    })
```

please help me:)

Comment: id == counter can never be true as id is defined to be counter + 1

Comment: What is the purpose of `AddNameInputs`? Why are you storing a component inside `temp`?

Comment: @TheoWckr yes i know, i only wrote it because the counter would not change to 1, the problem is that the counter stayes at 0

Comment: @goto1 AddNameInputs is a fuction made to add a new textinput component to my flatlist

Comment: Ah , i get it, setCounter is asynchronous so when you call `AddNameInputs` counter still equal 0 probably, i will try something

Answer (score 0):

This solved everything:)

```html
     useEffect(()=> 
        {AddNameInputs()}, [counter])
```

Comment: Yup, that's because setState function are asynchronous. You cant use their value in the follow of your code.